# inserting data in sqlite database using jtable

Tags: java, sqlite

private void bSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int rows = aw.getRowCount();
        for(int i=0;i

```
    try{ 
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Sales (ProductID,BuyerID,Quantity,Discount,Transactiontype,TransactionDate) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
        pst.setString(1, productID.getText()); 
        pst.setString(2,buyerid.getText()); 
        pst.setString(3, prodQty.getText()); 
        pst.setString(4, dc1.getText()); 
        pst.setString(5, Type.getSelectedItem().toString()); 
        pst.setString(6, dt.getText()); 
        pst.execute(); 
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved"); 
        rs.close(); 
        pst.close(); 
    }catch(Exception e){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); 
    } 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved!");} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post  problem in the code ?  If you need help on Sqlite-JDBC Lib Refer this link[SQLITE-JDBC](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/overview)

Comment: i already solved the problem .. but i got new problems in my sqlite database. its about foreign keys.. pls help